# Can't sign in with microsoft account on office 2016 programs(word 2016, excel 2016)

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-office-2016

I can't sign in microsoft account on office 2016 programs.

I click at 'sign in' and type my email and password and afterwards nothing happens. Other accounts doesn't work either. Erasing credentials from credential manager doesn't make a difference.

The program doesn't give any feedback about the sign in process it's very annoying in this sense. And all the tutorials online are for older versions and they are very unclear.

How to solve the problem? I need to sign in to see one drive documents and work in sync with others.